# Saving an email in python

Tags: python, email, gmail

I'm trying to save emails from my Gmail-account in ELM format. I'm trying to preserve as much information as possible (To, From, CC, attachments, etc.) because I want to convert this into PST format and recreate my outlook if needed in the future. I've only figured out how to save the contents of the email into an ELM-file, but I haven't been able to figure out how to save the other email information using this email library.

```
import imaplib
import email

#Login
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('email', 'pswd')


mail.list() # Lists all labels in GMail
mail.select('inbox') # Connected to inbox



result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")
ids = data[0] 
id_list = ids.split() 
i = len(data[0].split())
for x in range(i):
    latest_email_id = id_list[x] #get the latest
    result, data = result, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)") # fetch the email body (RFC822) for the given ID
    raw_email = data[0][1]


    raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)
    for part in email_message.walk():
     if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain": # ignore attachments/html
      body = part.get_payload(decode=True)

      save_string = str(r"C:\Users\Millar\Desktop\SavedEmailsTest\Dumpgmailemail_" + str(x) + ".eml")

      myfile = open(save_string, 'a')
      myfile.write(body.decode('utf-8'))
      myfile.close()
     else:
      continue
```

Comment: IMAP sounds like an inefficient protocol to do this. Why don't you download the archive from takeout?

Comment: Well initially I will use take out but I want to eventually download and save emails daily and store it in the cloud. I want to avoid having to download the entire archive on a daily basis